# citing historical newspapers

Tags: biblatex-chicago, newspaper

I'm compiling a chapter for an edited volume that includes numerous citations to historical newspapers. Most of these have no author or page number but only the (usually defunct) newspaper name and city of publication, article title, and full date of publication. For example:

```
@Article{NA1817,
  Title = {Cannon Foundry},
  Journal = {National Advocate},
  Date = {1817-07-30},
  Entrysubtype = {magazine},
  Location = {New York, NY}
}
```

I'm using `biblatex-chicago` with

```
\usepackage[%
  authordate,
  hyperref = auto,
  refsection = chapter,
  backend = biber
  ]{biblatex-chicago}
```

... `\autocite{NA1817}` results in an inline citation of (*National Advocate*,1817) and a bibliography entry that looks like:

*National Advocate* (New York, NY). 1817. "Cannon Foundry."

The bibliography list should show up as:

*National Advocate* (New York, NY). 1817. "Cannon Foundry." July 30.

My question is - how do I get the date (July 30) to show up somewhere in either the citation itself or the bibliography? It had been a few months ago when I started using `biblatex-chicago`, but at some point seems to have stopped for some reason. Only thing I changed in the package options was to set `refsection=chapter`...

MWE that compiles with the malformed bibliography on my machine:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

    @Article{NA1817,
    Title = {Cannon Foundry},
        Journaltitle = {National Advocate},
        Date = {1817-07-30},
        Entrysubtype = {magazine},
        options = {cmsdate=full},
        Location = {New York, NY}
        }

    % same type of entry (Author-less Article, Review, and Manual entries)
    % from cms-dates-intro.pdf  

    @Article{lakeforester:pushcarts,
        journaltitle = {Lake Forester},
        date = {2000-03-23},
        entrysubtype = {magazine},
        title = {Pushcarts Evolve to Trendy Kiosks},
        options = {cmsdate=full},
        location = {Lake Forest, IL}
        }

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
    authordate,
    backend=biber
    ]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Testing historical newspaper citation without author \autocites{NA1817}{lakeforester:pushcarts}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Still trying to track down a solution to this... I've added `options={cmsdate=full}` to the bib entries, which gets me the date in the in-line citation(e.g, _National Advocate_, July 30,1817) . Still not the date in the bibliography, though. I know it was at one point, but that seesm to have been turned off in a later update to the package or `biber` somehow... anyone know how to get it back?

Comment: I experimented with this a bit a few days ago, but there is lots and lots of date handling code in `biblatex-chicago`. Maybe an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) could at least help other to get involved more quickly. If can't get this done, you can of course send the package author a feature request mail, if what you plan is in line with CMS guidelines.

Comment: That's the curious part... I'm following the exact form of the bib entry recommended in the the latest cms-dates-intro.pdf that which does format the bibliographic list correctly with date for these types of entries, but getting a different result somehow.

Comment: Putting one together now.

Comment: I tried to have a look, but I got lost in some of the code for dates in `biblatex-chicago`. If this used to work and if it should work according to the CMS you could contact the author of the package and ask him.

Comment: @moewe, thanks. I may need to do that. There does seem to be something not working correctly for these, since they don't compile even to what the package author has as his examples.

Comment: So, it appears that the issue is a change in a more recent update of `biblatex` that has changed the bibliography list output, but have not been able to find a way to track it down yet. Have an email out to the `biblatex-chicago` package author. Anyone know how to revert to older package versions in TexLive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was in fact a conflict between `biber`/`biblatex` and the `biblatex-chicago` package (or at least in the `cms-*.lbx`). Got in touch with the package author, who is working on a fix. The MWE compiles correctly by the *CMS* spec with his patched `cms-*.lbx` file.